# How do I tell jQuery Validation that the AJAX validation is good?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin on a form. I've added an AJAX routine to validate one of the fields, the rest just need the regular validation methods.

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.validator.addMethod("unique_rep", function(value, element){
       $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(){
    spinnerStart();
      },
   type: "POST",
   url: "servertime3.php",
   data: "unique_rep="+value,
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(msg){
    spinnerStop(msg);
   }
      })
 },"");

  $("#register").validate({

     rules: {
    rep_id:{
     unique_rep: true,   
    },
    last_name:{
     required: true,
     minlength: 3
    },
    first_name:{
     required: false,
     minlength: 3
    },
    middle_initial:{
     maxlength: 1,
    },
    email:{
     required: false,
     email: true
    },
    url:{
     required: false,
     url: true
    }
   }
 })

});
```

*spinnerStart()* starts an in progress indicator next to the field.

*spinnerStop()* displays the result of the AJAX function which returns an array that contains 'ok'  which is true or false to show if the function succeeded and 'text' which is details of what went wrong.

This works fine EXCEPT that it's not submitting. Where and how do I tell the validation plugin that the rep_id field is valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `remote` option just for this? :) http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Comment: No, I'll check into it some more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that i understood your question, also i'm sure that you know this  but you also need to attach validate() plugin to a form..

```
$("#myform").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
   alert("submited!");
 }
});
```

Comment: Well, no I guess I didn't. I have $("#register").validate() in the code but not the submitHandler. Yes, confusion is arriving in a big dumptruck. ;-) All the validations, including my AJAX function are working great, I'm very happy with that. It's just when I click Submit nothing happens. If I make unique_rep:false then it works, so I think that somehow the AJAX call has to tell the plugin that the field contents are valid.

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think in your `addMethod`, the `success` must look like : `function(msg){    return spinnerStop(msg);}`
where **spinnerStop(msg)** returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yep, that's the kind thing I think I need. That didn't work though but I think that's what's needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By having properties like `required: true` you're setting up constraints for the plugin to match against.  The idea is for it to tell you if the form is valid or not.

Your question is a bit ambiguous.... I would narrow down the problem a bit m ore and you might get more answers... BUT here is me shooting  the hip..

### Try submitting the form manually:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   if($('form').valid()){
      $('form').submit();
   } else {
      return false;
   }
})
```

Comment: I thought that by adding that ajax method, the validation plugin would run the unique_rep function and then look for a return value from that function to decide if the contents of the field are valid. How does the plugin know if that field, or any of htem for that matter are valid?